# Simulate row number using numbers table

Tags: sql

How would I simulate row number for a table using a numbers table WITHOUT using ROW_NUMBER() function.

sample table:
create table accounts
(
   account_num VARCHAR(25),
   primary key (account_num)
)

The numbers table has 1mil rows.

Comment: How is `row_number()` not good for you? Not available?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're meaning, when it's not available (aka MySQL), try something like this:

```
select @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
       t.*
from (select * from table t order by col) t,
     (select @rownum := 0) r
```

It'll yield the same as:

```
select row_number() over (order by col)
from table
order by col
```

Comment: Is it possible using a numbers table though?

Answer (score 0):

A Numbers table does not help you here because you have no means to associate a value in your table with a number in the Numbers table. However, if you are asking whether it is possible to create a sequence without using ROW_NUMBER() or a variable, you can do it like so:

```
Select A1.Account_Num, Count( A2.Account_Num ) + 1 As Num
From Accounts As A1
    Left Join Accounts As A2
        On A2.Account_Num < A1.Account_Num
Group By A1.Account_Num
```