# How to create view in sql with row number ? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, create-view

Is it possible to create view with row number ?

```
CREATE VIEW view_table
AS SELECT a.entity_id, a.firstname, a.lastname, 
b.vacation_start_day, b.vacation_end_day
FROM customer_info_table a, customer_vacations b
```

[image]

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Comment: .... you can use RANK()/DENSE_RANK()/ROW_NUMBER() there depending of what you want to do with "ties"

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: ... but keep in mind that MySQL user variables do **not** work in [views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021149/how-to-generate-sequence-number-in-mysql-view/42022625#42022625) if you don't have MySQL 8... You would have to use a co-related subquery with a count to simulate it which is slow..

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` window function avaible since MySQL 8.0. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Comment: I'm curious - what value would row number be to you?

Comment: The entity id is repeated, and it interferes with my function, I need special values for each row in one column.